# Export user input and table out put to one Excel file with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have written an app allowing users to provide some inputs. The app will call a function to do some calculations and generate an output in table format.

I would like to add a button that allows users to download both the inputs and outputs into an Excel spreadsheet (with two tabs)

Below is a simplified version of the code where I want to download the inputs and the example table. I have tried the following code but failed:

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
somefunction <- function() { 
   data.frame(text = c("sample1","sample2"))}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataReactive <- reactive({
    data.frame(text = c(input$text1, input$text2, input$text3))

  })

  observeEvent(input$goButton,{
    output$exampleTable <- DT::renderDataTable({somefunction()})
  })

  output$downloadExcelSheet <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("result",Sys.Date(), ".xlsx",sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.xlsx(list(dataReactive(),exampleTable), file)
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text1","Text 1:",value="Input 1"),
      textInput("text2","Text 2:",value="Input 2"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Calculate"),
      downloadButton("downloadExcelSheet", "Download Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("exampleTable")
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {

    dataReactive <- reactive({
      data.frame(text = c(input$text1, input$text2, input$text3))

    })
    data <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$goButton,{
      output$exampleTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        data$df <- somefunction()
      })
    })
    output$downloadExcelSheet <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("result",Sys.Date(), ".xlsx",sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.xlsx(list(dataReactive(),data$df), file)
      })
  }
```

It's better to move `data$df <- somefunction()` to `observeEvent` and move `DT::renderDataTable` outside `observeEvent` like so

```
observeEvent(input$goButton,{
       data$df <- somefunction()
})
output$exampleTable <- DT::renderDataTable({data$df})
```

Use `reactiveValues` as an intermediate state to save variables and in order to reuse them later.

Comment: Thanks. What if my actual data is generated via an action button? I have updated the above code to show how it actually looks like. I tried to incorporate your code but I kept getting error [No stack trace available]